# My application lags on an iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an application that functions well on the simulator, but when I transfer the application onto an iPod Touch, the application fails - it kind of lags.

My application makes use of a navigation controller with a UITable view. When the table is selected, a detail view will be shown. On the detail view there is a next button which will show the next detail view.

Comment: The simulator tends to run faster than a device. In what way is your application lagging?

Comment: when i click on the next button to show the other detail view. The bgimage and textview will not show on the new detail view

Comment: Check the upper/lower case spelling of all your image file names.

Comment: all name are correct. But after a while the view will appear

Comment: How large / what format are your image files? Perhaps they could be down-sampled to smaller sizes so they are faster to load?

Answer (score 0):

Use Instruments and another tools to profile your application to see where it spends time (= lagging).